# add multiple rows to database depending on value selected in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, save

My form has input check boxes for each month.

Now i m trying to add multiple rows to database. Database rows are like Customername|Code|Month

Value should get added as below when Jan,Mar,May and Jul check boxes are selected.

Aravind|AM4298|Jan;

Aravind|AM4298|Mar;

Aravind|AM4298|May;

Aravind|AM4298|Jul;

how does save function in cakephp loop the input values through multiple rows. Can someone please explain with example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you set up your [Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) (may or may not be necessary in this case), then you make sure your `<form>` is created correctly via the [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html).

The end result will be that when you run a [saveAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array) with the data posted from your form, it will save an array of data into multiple database rows.